# Formal Languages - Context Free Grammar

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Describe the formal language over the alphabet
{
a,b,c
}
generated
by the context-free grammar whose non-terminals are
〈
S
〉
and
〈
A
〉
,
whose  start  symbol  is
〈
S
〉
,
and  whose  production  rules  are  the
following:
(1)
〈
S
〉→
a
〈
S
〉
(2)
〈
S
〉→
b
〈
A
〉
(3)
〈
A
〉→
b
〈
A
〉
(4)
〈
A
〉→
c
〈
A
〉
(5)
〈
A
〉→
c
(6)
〈
S
〉→
a
In other words, describe the structure of the strings generated by
this grammar and modify to NORMAL FORM(The normal form pasrt I am struggling with)

Comment: Im confused about how I should write my answer and how to format production rules

Comment: I've made some progress, I currently have: { a^n b^m c^p | n >= 0, m >= 0, p >= 0 } , not sure how to format it to mean that b cannot come at the end of a word... how could i do this?

Comment: It seems this grammar is even regular, since all rules are of the form non-terminal produces terminal or non-terminal produces terminal followed by non-terminal (this is one of the standard forms of a regular grammar). Given this, try to express the language as a regular expression.

Comment: Also your description { a^n b^m c^p | n >= 0, m >= 0, p >= 0 } is not (yet) completely correct. There is a difference between words starting with a letter a and those starting with a letter b and what about the order of letters b and c?

Comment: I tried express the language as a regular expression, is this correct?

Comment: G = regular Grammar. G =(N,S,L,R). N = {S,A} //non terminal symbols. S = S1 //Start Symbol . L  ={a,b,c} // alphabet terminals. R= {S1 -> S(N1,N2,N3) , N1->a, N2->a(S1), N3 -> b(A), A->(N4, N5, N6) , N4-> c, N5-> b(A), N6-> c(A)} // Nn = dataNodes, n >0

Comment: Is this grammar in normal form? If it is not in normal form, then
modify it to make it be in normal form. Explain why it generates
the same language after your modifications.

Comment: How would I approach this question

Answer (score 0):

The language is indeed regular and can be described by the regular expression
$$ a^+\ \cup\ \  (a^*\cdot\{b,c\}^*\cdot c) $$

Concerning the normal form, you need to specify which normal form you are talking about. For right-regular grammars the most common one requires exactly one terminal on the right-hand side of each rule. This holds for your grammar.

Comment: I'm curious what the little cross means beside the a

Comment: It is a plus. A short form for non-empty iteration: $a^+ = a\cdot a^*$.

Comment: Unfortunately the given regular expression is not completely correct either. E.g. the word bc is in the language but can not be produced from the given regular expression.

Comment: Thanks @MHS! I think I have corrected the expression.